# Ember - JSON import - not displaying template content

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-cli

I am working with the Ember CLI.

I have a JSON in this format:

**public/assets/data.json**

```
{
  "important": [
    {
      "name": "first",
      "value": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "second",
      "value": 10
    },
    ...
  ],
  "unimportant1": {
    ...
  },
  "unimportant2": {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I want to import `"important"` for use in a model.
I have attempted the following:

**app/routes/important.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.$.getJSON("/assets/data.json").important;
  }
});
```

The console log does not display any errors.

I want to display the items in `"important"`.
I have attempted the following:

**app/templates/important.hbs**

```
{{#each model as |important|}}
  <div>
    {{important.name}}{{important.value}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

However, nothing is displayed. How can I get them to display?

I noticed that the items display as expected if I copy and paste the array into the return statement:

**app/routes/important.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return [
      {
        "name": "first",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "name": "second",
        "value": 10
      },
      ...
    ];
  }
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ember.$.getJSON("/assets/data.json");` returns a promise, but `Ember.$.getJSON("/assets/data.json").important;` does not return a promise. It is just an `undefined`.

In your model hook, just return the promise:

```
model() {
  return Ember.$.getJSON("/assets/data.json");
}
```

Then in your template, use it like:

```
{{#each model.important as |important|}}
  <div>
    {{important.name}}{{important.value}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```